# How does Dagger2's built-in AssistedInject support factories that return interfaces instead of classes

Tags: interface, dagger-2, assisted-inject

I'm poking around with Dagger2 and its built-in AssisedInject annotation. The tutorial available at [dagger.dev](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection.html) shows an example where the factory method returns a concrete class but I would have expected the factory to return an interface for which an implementation binding is defined in some module.

```
class MyDataService {
  @AssistedInject
  MyDataService(DataFetcher dataFetcher, @Assisted Config config) {}
}

// ---

@AssistedFactory
public interface MyDataServiceFactory {
  MyDataService create(Config config);
}
```

In Google Guice, e.g. I can create a module with a factory module builder to tie together interface and implementation:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
     .implement(Payment.class, RealPayment.class)
     .build(PaymentFactory.class));
```

Isn't that possible with Dagger2 AssistedInject? I'm pretty new to Dagger, perhaps I misunderstood the concept at that point. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible:

Annotated your parameter that you want to be assisted, then declare a factory (can be abstract or interface) inside your concrete implementation that implements another `Factory` interface that returns the interface you want to bind, but now you return your concrete implementation by overriding the interface Factory return type

```
interface RequestSetFactory {
    fun create(address: String): RequestSet
}
class MyRequestSet @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val deviceAddress: String,
) : RequestSet {

    @AssistedFactory
    abstract class Factory : RequestSetFactory {
        abstract override fun create(address : String): MyRequestSet
    }
    //.... impl code
}
```

In the binding module just add the mapping as:

```
@Module
abstract class RequestSetProviderBindingModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @StringKey(Key.MY_KEY) //<-- change this 
    abstract fun bindMyRequests(my: MyRequestSet.Factory): RequestSetFactory
}
```

Declare the provider map in your instance factory as:

```kotlin
typealias RequestSetProviderMap = Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<RequestSetFactory>>
```